# Overload with generic type parameter instead?

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, overloading

I'd like to add a generic type method `DoSomething<T>`, but for backwards compatibility, I want it to simply pass the type parameter for the generic type from an existing method with the same name.

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Data data)
{
    //do something with Data, it depends on the type of T
}

public void DoSomething(Data data, Type dataType)
{
    DoSomething<dataType>(group);
}
```

However, `<dataType>` in the new `DoSomething` throws following type checking error: "Type name or namespace expected."

Can someone help me understand the gap in my thinking that makes the above sample a type checking error? Is what I'm doing just... bad design?

Comment: dataType is still an instance of a Type object...not a type definition you can use to declare new generic objects. You need to call the generic version of your method using Reflection.

Comment: Actually, there'S a second reason why this wouldn't work. Your are trying to call an instance method from a static method.

Comment: @Max: Thanks, I updated my sample to be correctly relevant to the question I was more interested in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generics is about knowing the type at *compile-time* - you only know the type at *execution time*.

There are two ways of fixing this:

- Make the generic code call the non-generic code instead. That's easy, but you won't have any of the benefits of generics.
- Use reflection to call the generic code from the non-generic code. That's fiddly and won't perform as well, but you can deprecate the non-generic code and eventually remove it.

Or you could just remove it now, and fix everything up :)

Comment: If it's really an issue; with some compiled lambda expressions you can get this quite fast as well :-)

Comment: The fact that Generics wire up at compile-time is what I was missing when I tried to write code that looked like Mike Atlas' example.

Answer (score 7):

I generally find it easier to reverse the relationship between the methods, i.e.:

```
private void DoSomething<T>(Data data)
{
    DoSomething(data, typeof(T));
}

private void DoSomething(Data data, Type dataType)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what you have to do.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you are mixing generic argument and runtime type information.  The type values used for a generic arguments must be established at compile time and are embedded in metadata.  The type `Type` is a construct whose value is not known at compile time.  Hence the 2 are not compatible.

Your best bet here is to make the original DoSomething method the primary method and have the new generic one feed into it.

```
static void DoSomething<T>(Data data) {
  DoSomething(data, typeof(T));
}

static void DoSomething(Data data, Type dataType) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a private method, what concern is there for external backwards compatibility?